# TinyMCE, filter tags and attributes before editing

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE remove tags and attributes that are not allowed. But this happens only on save/post.

However, I want to filter the content BEFORE editing, so that if content with invalid tags/attributes is fetched (from a DB or whatever), they are removed.

How can I do that ?

Note: this is also a security hole, because it is not possible to encode html entities, and javascript can be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An old version was in use, upgrading solved it !